# Removing baked on paint from stainless steel grill

Tags: paint-removal

I purchased a used grill that's in great condition except the previous owner got spray paint on the stainless steel grill and continued to use it. I was able to remove some of it with acetone and graffiti remover, but can't seem to get the rest off - I assume because of it repeatedly being heated to high temperatures.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Sanding/grinding is also a go to method to remove paint/stuff.  Real stainless steel should be okay, if a coating(like chrome) maybe not okay.

Comment: My approach has generally been that if it won't come off with soap, scrubbing, and fire it probably won't come off with food.

Comment: You can get grill scrapers with semicircular notches to scrape the wire clean.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few methods.

- Paint stripper
- Soak in caustic soda
- Angle grinder with a twist knot wire wheel

These are all dangerous, Read the instructions and wear appropriate protection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Easy Off Heavy Duty?

It worked like a charm to clean stove that had yrs of grease, food, & melted plastic all over range. Thought it was trashed but ended up looking brand new.

Spray liberally (in well ventilated area or you’ll definitely cough - maybe even cancer), leave it on for an hour+, wipe. Once usually does trick, but 2x is even better

It’s a cheap easy thing to try before you start trying major projects. I paid $5 online